# How to delay the onLoad event which gets fired on the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, yui

I am trying to delay the onLoad event that gets fired. 
Is there a way to delay this event strictly using javascript on the client side ?

Comment: A good reason to want to delay the actual onload event (or other aspects of window load completion) is for testing, in case the delay would affect other things on the page significantly.  I just found this question looking for exactly that.

Comment: A good reason to want to delay the actual onload event is for WebAssembly apps for search engines

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you put a `script` tag at the end of the `body` like:

```
<body>

  ...

  <script>
    setTimeout(function(){
      //deferred onload
    }, 2000);
  </script>
</body>
```

The function will be executed after 2 sec in this case

As said in my comment below: *you shouldn't rely on a delay. But use a callback on a certain event. If impossible, may be a better bad solution, is to use setInterval with a function that check every X msec if the thing you are waiting for is present, and fire.*

Comment: nope that does not work. setTimeout does not hold back the onload event to be fired.

Comment: Sorry it was not clear, don't use the `onload` event anymore, but replace it with this technique to delay the start of your code.

Comment: @Kunal you shouldn't rely on a delay. But use a callback on a certain event. If impossible, may be a better bad solution, is to use `setInterval` with a function that check every X msec if the thing you are waiting for is present, and fire.

Answer (score -9):

There's no reason to delay the onload event.  Maybe you want to use window.load instead?

```
$(window).load(function(){
    //your code here
});
```

Comment: i want to delay the onload event.

Comment: What's the reason for delaying the onLoad event?  It seems to me like it'd be better to wait for onload, then delay your code.  There's something I'm missing here.

Comment: I write code for an external container and the container detects load event. That's why I want to delay it.