# How to delay the onLoad function in HTML

Tags: html, button, onload

I have made a website with multiple pages, where I pass variables to pages via POST, and I do this by clicking buttons, however, on one particular page, I want the button to be invisible, and because of this, it needs to be able to click itself, now I can do this by using the onLoad function when it is visible, but it goes too quickly, I need it to wait a few seconds before calling it, and when I make the button invisible, the function doesn't work at all! How would I best go about doing this? Thanks

My button:

```
<input type="submit" id="GoButton" value="Login" class="btn-login"/>
```

My button when I hide it:

```
<input type="hidden" id="GoButton" value="Login" class="btn-login"/>
```

My onLoad:

```
<body onLoad="document.getElementById('GoButton').click();">
</body>
```

Comment: _“when I make the button invisible, the function doesn't work at all”_ — could you [edit] your question and share the code to demonstrate how exactly you make the button invisible?

Comment: Why delay? `setTimeout` only if absolutely needed *(like some weird Browser specific issue)*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delay the onLoad event which gets fired on the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800048/how-to-delay-the-onload-event-which-gets-fired-on-the-browser)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can delay the action with `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(
    function() {
        document.getElementById('GoButton').click();
    },
    5000
);
```

The `delay` parameter is the number of milliseconds to wait.

Comment: Where exactly would I put this? and would I need to put it in <Script> tags? Sorry I'm very new to this xD